# How to define ruby code inside a haml file present in javascript folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, ruby, haml

For my project, I am using `Ruby on Rails` and `Angular` and I have a `haml` file present in `/project_name/app/assets/javascript` folder. I want to call a ruby class from the `haml` file but unfortunately I am not able to do that.

```
 .small-12.columns
    .booking-time
      %span.bold
        - if ABC::D.data(:hide_hours_field)  #ruby code 
          {{ item | timeformat }}
        - else
          {{ item | differentTimeFormat }}
```

Whenever I start the server, it's is showing it can't access the ruby class. I can easily access the ruby class in other `haml` files but not the one present in javascript folder. Can anyone help me here?

Comment: What does `ABC::D` _actually_ look like? Not some instance variables, I hope?

Comment: No. it's not a instance variable. `class ABC::D`

Comment: I can access the same class from other `haml` files present in my project but not the one defined inside javascript folder.

Comment: you won't be able to do that, but I can't explain exactly why, at the moment. :/ In short, that is angular template, it should be managed by angular.

Comment: Can I call ruby code from angular controller?

Comment: definitely not :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: I'm bad at Angular (and didn't even touch version 2). What follows is not a best practice or anything.

So, you need to configure your angular view with some knowledge from ruby side. You can't conditionally render it and you can't call ruby from angular controllers (obviously). I suggest smuggling data via `window` object.

In an appropriate view in your application, put this JS snippet.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    window.jsEnv = {
      hide_hours_field: <%= ABC::D.data[:hide_hours_field] %> 
    }
</script>
```

Then you can reference that via `$window` object in angular

Controller

```
function MyController($window) {
  this.hideHours = function() {
    return !!$window.jsEnv.hide_hours_field;
  }
}

MyController.$inject = ['$window'];

angular.module('myApp').controller('MyController', MyController);
```

View

```
.small-12.columns(ng-controller='MyController as vm')
  .booking-time
    %span.bold(ng-if='vm.hideHours()')
      {{ item | timeformat }}
    %span.bold(ng-unless='vm.hideHours()')
      {{ item | differentTimeFormat }}
```

Comment: what is `myApp` here `angular.module('myApp').controller('MyController', MyController);`

Comment: my editor is showing that `ng-controller` is not allowed on `.small-12.columns(ng-controller='MyController as vm')`  any thoughts?

Comment: @python: that was just an example. You surely have a controller used on that page elsewhere. Use that controller.

Comment: I found the file where I should add this code ```<script type='text/javascript'>
    window.jsEnv = {
      hide_hours_field: <%= ABC::D.data[:hide_hours_field] %> 
    }
</script>``` but it's a `haml` file. Can I define this code in `haml` file ?

Comment: Yes, only use HAML's `:javascript` filter

Comment: okay brother, it worked :D thank you so much for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use angular constant instead of window then you can use it as **service**:

```
    // index.html
    <script type="text/javascript">
      angular.module('myApp').constant('CURRENT_USER', #{current_user.to_json})
    </script>

    // controller
    function ApiConsoleController($scope, CURRENT_USER) {
      console.debug(CURRENT_USER)
    }
```

Also, you can try to use [angular-rails-templates](https://github.com/pitr/angular-rails-templates)

```
    // application.rb
    config.angular_templates.ignore_prefix = %w(
      angular/components/
      angular/shared/
      angular/directives/
      angular/validators/
    )
```